# How to change the texture of a model

Tags: three.js, blender, gltf, light

I'm new to three.js and hit a bit of a dead end.
I want to place the specified gltf model in the scene:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wpabaMXR5NEBJ3f-2Sl7SnnwbzndCQ3X/view?usp=drive_link

I manage to get it into the scene, add light, but this model doesn't look like it looks in blender.
It's dark and the auto paint looks unrealistic and dull.

Can anyone tell me if the problem is in the model or I'm missing some parameters when adding it to the scene to make it look normal?

The js code is spelled out below and is also available on my github at the link below:

https://github.com/Dizelars/three.js_project/blob/main/src/my_three.js

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { DRACOLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader.js';
import gsap from "gsap";

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    precision: "lowp",
    antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let activeScene = 1;


const scene1 = new THREE.Scene();
scene1.background = new THREE.Color(0x000000);

const initialCameraPosition1 = new THREE.Vector3(-171.85716505033145, 74.93456415868356, 86.89998171402281);
const camera1 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera1.position.copy(initialCameraPosition1);

const controls1 = new OrbitControls(camera1, renderer.domElement);
controls1.minPolarAngle = 0;
controls1.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.5;
controls1.minDistance = 6;
controls1.maxDistance = 1000;
controls1.enabled = true;
controls1.update();


// Create Ambient and Point lights for the scene
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
const pointLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
pointLight.position.set(4.535622620739531, 280.0453245202818, 24.052762487525687);
scene1.add(ambientLight);
scene1.add(pointLight);

const pointLightHelper = new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper(pointLight);
scene1.add( pointLightHelper );


let gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
const dLoader = new DRACOLoader();
dLoader.setDecoderPath('https://www.gstatic.com/draco/versioned/decoders/1.5.6/');
dLoader.setDecoderConfig({type: 'js'});
gltfLoader.setDRACOLoader(dLoader);
let obj;
let url = 'car3.gltf';
gltfLoader.load(url, function(gltf) {
    obj = gltf.scene;
    obj.traverse((child) => {
        if (child.isMesh) {
            child.material.metalness = 0.8;
            child.material.roughness = 0.2;
            child.emissive = 0x0
        }
    });
    scene1.add(obj);
    console.log(obj);
    obj.position.set(0, 0, 0);

    window.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
        console.log(camera1.position); // Выводим координаты камеры
    });
});


const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(85);
scene1.add(axesHelper);

function MyCoordinates(xPos, yPos, zPos, dur) {
    gsap.to(camera1.position, {
        x: xPos,
        y: yPos,
        z: zPos,
        duration: dur,
        onUpdate: function() {
            camera1.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
        }
    });
}

const coordinates = [
    [-4.709869959805082, 1.3231521819422856, -3.4736714388593297, 1.5],
    [4.419631461529943, 1.366719430512851, -3.82085536791349, 1.5],
    [4.612135343130454, 3.8370701385486443, 0.07141658424494553, 1.5],
    [4.548391730389692, 1.5106187886098281, 3.6097317826151065, 1.5],
    [-5.680156277820456, 1.5032113113583057, 2.3163283637778207, 1.5],
    [-1.6416573959597511, 1.1981686266100635, 1.2447508461030132, 1.5]
];

const go_to = document.querySelectorAll('.go_to');

go_to.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const [x, y, z, dur] = coordinates[i];
        MyCoordinates(x, y, z, dur);
    });
});


const scene2 = new THREE.Scene();
scene2.background = new THREE.Color(0x000000);

const initialCameraPosition2 = new THREE.Vector3(-0.0006, -0.00006, 0.0001);
const camera2 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera2.position.copy(initialCameraPosition2);

const controls2 = new OrbitControls(camera2, renderer.domElement);
controls2.enabled = false;
controls2.update();

const hLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 2);
scene2.add(hLight);

const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

function animate() {
    if (activeScene === 1) {
        renderer.render(scene1, camera1);
    } else {
        renderer.render(scene2, camera2);
    }
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate);

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    camera1.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera1.updateProjectionMatrix();
    camera2.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera2.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
});


const interiorButton = document.querySelector('.interior');
interiorButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (activeScene === 1) {
        const [x, y, z, dur] = coordinates[5];
        MyCoordinates(x, y, z, dur);
        setTimeout(() => {
            activeScene = 2;
            const [x2, y2, z2, dur2] = initialCameraPosition1.toArray();
            MyCoordinates(x2, y2, z2, dur2);
            controls1.enabled = false;
            controls2.enabled = true;
            animate();
        }, dur * 1000);
    } else {
        const [x, y, z, dur] = coordinates[4];
        MyCoordinates(x, y, z, dur);
        activeScene = 1;
        setTimeout(() => {
            const [x2, y2, z2, dur2] = initialCameraPosition1.toArray();
            MyCoordinates(x2, y2, z2, dur2);
            controls1.enabled = true;
            controls2.enabled = false;
            animate();
        }, dur * 1000);
    }
});
```